# Difference between ps -e and ps -A

Tags: linux, process

I was going through the help page of ps command (using ps --h) and I noticed the two options have the same description.

```
-e all processes
-A all processes
```

I ran the commands with both the options and I noticed no difference.

Is there any difference between the two options? If not why to provide two options that does the same?

Comment: Both answers below are correct. Please note that such commands are not only used (implemented for) one single system (read: operating system, specific environment), but are equally used on several systems. It is desireable to have the commadnreact the same regardless on what system you use it. So if two implementation existed, one using `-A`, the other using `-e` then a common implementation behaves 'right' for everyone when _both_ variants are implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

man ps said:

```
 -A     Select all processes.  Identical to -e.
```

As mentioned above, this may be done for compatibility with older scripts for different UNIX systems, it happens.

(archlinux distro).

Comment: But this doesn't answer my second question. If they are identical why do both of them exist?

Comment: ehm, i answered - for compatibility. in older nonstandartized unix systems there were many implementations of commands, and sometimes they used different options for the same things. when people wanted to use other system's script with minimum maintenance effort, they sometimes decided to mimic the options in command itself, keeping 'ours and theirs' options parameneters for the compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

> why to provide two options that does the same?

Probably for compatibility with `ps` on other (legacy?) systems.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer? I could not understand what other ps commands mean here.

Comment: I started learning Linux and was not able to figure out difference between "ps" and "ps -A". "ps -A" is giving long list of running process. whereas "ps" without any option simply give 2 entries. bydefault ps will give what all processes?